# AttributeError in python: object has no attribute

Tags: python-3.x, machine-learning, neural-network

I started learning **Machine Learning** and came across **Neural Networks**. while implementing a program i got this error. i have tried checking for every solution but no luck. here's my code:

```
from numpy import exp, array, random, dot

class neural_network:
    def _init_(self):
        random.seed(1)
        self.weights = 2 * random.random((2, 1)) - 1

    def train(self, inputs, outputs, num):
        for iteration in range(num):
            output = self.think(inputs)
            error = outputs - output
            adjustment = 0.01*dot(inputs.T, error)
            self.weights += adjustment

    def think(self, inputs):
        return (dot(inputs, self.weights))



neural = neural_network()

# The training set
inputs = array([[2, 3], [1, 1], [5, 2], [12, 3]])
outputs = array([[10, 4, 14, 30]]).T

# Training the neural network using the training set.
neural.train(inputs, outputs, 10000)

# Ask the neural network the output
print(neural.think(array([15, 2])))
```

this is the error which i'm getting when running `neural.train`:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "neural.py", line 27, in <module>
    neural.train(inputs, outputs, 10000)
File "neural.py", line 10, in train
    output = self.think(inputs)
File "neural.py", line 16, in think
    return (dot(inputs, self.weights))
AttributeError: 'neural_network' object has no attribute 'weights'
```

Though its has a self attribute **self.weights()** still it says no such attribute.

Comment: `def _init_(self):`. You meant `def __init__(self):` (`_` * 2)

Comment: @Arount isn't this what I had just answered?

Comment: @desertnaut yea, one minute before me.

Comment: thankyou desertnaut and Arount

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, it turns out that your initialization method [should be named](https://micropyramid.com/blog/understand-self-and-__init__-method-in-python-class/) `__init__` (two underscores), *not* `_init_`...

So, changing the method to

```
def __init__(self):
    random.seed(1)
    self.weights = 2 * random.random((2, 1)) - 1
```

your code works OK:

```
neural.train(inputs, outputs, 10000)
print(neural.think(array([15, 2])))
# [ 34.]
```

Answer (score 0):

Your initializing method is written wrong, its two underscores `__init__(self):` not one underscore`_init_(self):`

Otherwise, nice code!